# Add color in database

Tags: javascript, php, css

Hello i was creating a chat,and i add in my database color where every user can choose his own color.This look like this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY5t9.png
I add manualy green color for my user.And i want when somebody click on this colors at bottom to change his color in database.Here is my code

```
<div id="inputform">
    <form name="forma1" action="#" id="forma1" onsubmit=Klikni();>
        <input type="textarea" class="msginput" name="msg"><br />
        <a href="#" onclick="Klikni()"; class="button">Posalji</a>
        <div id="boje-div">
            <a class="link-boje" name="zelena" id="link-zelena" href="#" onclick="Boja()";value="32321"><div class="boje" id="boja_zelena"></div></a>
            <a class="link-boje" id="link-crvena" href="#"><div class="boje" id="boja_crvena"></div>
            <a class="link-boje" id="link-plava" href="#"><div class="boje" id="boja_plava"></div>
            <a class="link-boje" id="link-zuta" href="#"><div class="boje" id="boja_zuta"></div>
            <a class="link-boje" id="link-narandzasta" href="#"><div class="boje" id="boja_narandzasta"></div>
```

In script:

```
   function Boja(e){

var color = forma1.zelena.value='e213312';

$con = mysql_connect('fdb13421f','184694214124t','matur421;
mysql_select_db('184421hat',$con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO korisnici (color) VALUES ('$color')");
}
But t
```

his code wont value in my database.And i add this php for every color.This is example for one color green.

Comment: `$color=zelena.value;` doesn't look like valid php. before mysql_query `var_dump($color);` and check what it is, and if it's even running

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you try if you are getting value from `$color`, try `echo $color;` and see what do you see in browser?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code.

First of all, you are trying to call a php function from onClick, which is for Javascript functions.

Second, zelena.value is not how you get the value of a form item.

There are more issues. I suggest you look up some beginner tutorials on PHP forms and start from there.

Comment: You need to look up some of the basics of PHP and form submission, there is more wrong with this script then there is right. I'm not going to code it for you, there are plenty of tutorials out there. You are mixing Javascript and PHP in the same function.